# How to count before new insertion using the values from the insert statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger in which it will count the number of a occurrence and deny any new insertion if it hits more than a number.

In my case, if I attempt to add in a new `testing` with the `testerid` which is 1001 (`testing` table already have 3 records with `testerid` of `1001`), it should denied the insertion.

```
create table tester
(
    testerid int,
    CONSTRAINT testerpk PRIMARY KEY (testerid)
);

create table testing
(
    testingid int,
    testingdate date,
    testerid int,
    CONSTRAINT testerfk FOREIGN KEY (testerid) REFERENCES tester(testerid)
);

insert into tester
values (1001);
insert into tester
values (1002);
insert into testing
values (1, (Date '2020-10-10'), 1001);
insert into testing
values (2, (Date '2020-10-11'), 1001);
insert into testing
values (3, (Date '2020-10-12'), 1001);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg
BEFORE INSERT
ON testing
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    val number;

BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO val
    FROM testing
    WHERE :new.testerid = testerid
    HAVING val < 3;
END;

insert into testing
values (10, (Date '2020-11-17'), 1001);
```

How do I write in my trigger the check for the inputted `testerid`?
I tried `WHERE :new.testerid = testerid` but I think that is wrong, as I could not tell if the `testerid` is indeed stemming from the input statement .

Here is my [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=591a2d1545c41ee37255797ca9810f5b) (it is throwing errors)

Comment: In your fiddle, at the end you are selecting from table `reading`. Typo?

Comment: I fear this is an XY problem where you're asking about your solution when you should be focused on your goal. While Barbaros's solution does exactly what you ask for, it will *not* always prevent a tester from having three rows. The trigger cannot see what has happened but not yet been committed in other transactions - if two sessions insert two rows at the same time, they both pass the check, and then after the commit there are now four rows for the same tester. Do you need to worry about such multi-user environments?

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of `HAVING` Clause ( even `GROUP BY` expression is not needed ). Use below code without raising any exception with `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` added in order to check out whether the `val` exceeds three :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg
BEFORE INSERT ON testing
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  val INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO val 
    FROM testing 
   WHERE testerid = :new.testerid;

  IF val = 3 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20202,
                            'Each tester may have three records at most !');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9b8c04de659feffb3fbcbd4d16c69d27)</kbd>

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, could I kindly ask what does `20202` means? Been trying to source for the list of numbers and its meaning but wasn't able to find much

Comment: Hi @j.hall . That's nothing but a code that should be given within the range of -20000 and  -20999 reserved for user defined exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following approach:

1. In `tester` add a count column.
2. In `tester` add a `check` constraint:  `check (testing <= 3)`.
3. Add triggers on `testing` to keep the count up-to-date.

I think this is the simplest method for keeping a maximum number of records in Oracle.